# Creating an id based on schema data that is both unique and prevents duplicates

Tags: python, database, mongodb, primary-key

So i am inserting data that looks like this.. into my mongo db colletion, it is some polling data

[Link to sample insertions](https://pastebin.com/WTJxDKSS)

What i plan on doing is combining the "Poll_Name", "Date", "Sample_Size" and "MoE" values into a unique string and then using some function to convert it into a unique id value.

What i wish to get out of this function is the ability to both create an id for each poll and create a duplicate id if a duplicate string is given.

So for example lets say i wish to  add this poll to my database..

```
{'Poll_Name': 'NBC News/Marist', 'Date': '2020-03-10', 'Sample_Size': '2523 RV', 'MoE': '2.7', 'Biden (D)': '47', 'Trump(R)': '46', 'Spread': 'Biden +1'}
```

and i create an id from this poll using its "Poll_Name", "Date", "Sample_Size" and "MoE" values

so the string would come out something like this...

```
poll_String = "NBC News/Marist2020-03-102523RV2.7"
```

And then i put it through the function that creates an id and lets say it spits out the value "12345" (for simplicity sake)
Then lets say later on in the insertions, i am adding an exact duplicate of this poll, so the "poll_String" comes out the exact same for this poll duplicate.

I need the id creation function to return the exact same value ie 12345, so that i know then that the poll being added here is a duplicate. And obviously in the process keep the id created completely unique to other polls that differ, so as not to create incorrect duplicate ids.

Is this possible? or am i asking for something too advanced...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hashing function to create a hash of the data.
But you will need to consider that hashing data will not guarantee that another piece of data will not have the same hash, it would just be very unlikely.
So consider the following code

```
import hashlib
some_string = "Some test string I want to generate an ID from"
new_id = hashlib.md5(some_string.encode()).hexdigest()
print(new_id)
```

This snippet will print `051ba4078ab8419b76388ee9173dac1a`.
Please note that md5 hashes [should not be used to store passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure).

Also, if you want the id to be shorter than this you can simply take the first `x` characters of the hash. But remember, the shorter the id, the higher the chance of you getting two pieces of data with the same auto-generated id.

The odds of two different pieces of data to have the same auto-generated id with this method is roughly 1/16^x. Consider how much data you have and how unlikely you'd want id collisions to happen. over 99% in a lifetime of an application is reasonable in my opinion.
So if you have say 100M items, taking the first 10 hexadecimal characters from the md5 hash will give you a likelihood of about 0.01% to have a collision (assuming of course no who items are the same).

Also, it isn't random, so for the same string you will always get the same hash value.